# Kotlin coroutine stops launching on every fragment instantiation except the first, using ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I use a coroutine to launch suspended fun `emitList`

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _list = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ListItem>>()
    val _list: LiveData<ArrayList<ListItem>>
        get() = _list

    fun refresh() = viewModelScope.launch {
        emitList()
    }

    private suspend fun emitList() = runIfBounded {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // run some database access code
            // post results to _list
        }
    }

}
```

coroutine launches, but when the fragment the vm is used for is destroyed and recreated by the ViewPager, the coroutine no longer launches.

The idea is to post a list of items generated from a database query every time the fragment is instantiated. But for some reason, the coroutine only launches for the first instantiated fragment and not any fragment thereafter.

Here in fragment's `onResume` I call `refresh`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    viewModel.refresh()
}
```

I'm just confused. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to use

```
GlobalScope.launch { }
```

not

```
viewModelScope.launch { }
```